# Can't figure out this basic algebra

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Been a while since I did math but I'm trying to understand how they got the final equation in this step:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1haw.png

When I solve for P I get this:
$$
P(t) = \frac{300Ce^{0.1t}}{1+Ce^{0.1t}}
$$

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct. Multiply both top and bottom by $Ce^{-0.1t}$ to get to their answer.